# Enum Type in F# Library Not Visible in Linked Program

Tags: enums, f#, static-libraries

After I build the library below and then link a program with it, the functions `libInit`, `driveList`, and `freeSpace` are visible to the program that linked to the library, which is what I expect.

I do not know how to reference the enums contained in the library. Are the enums visible or can they be made visible to the linked program, and, if so, how are they referenced?

```
namespace Toa.volLib
open System
open System.Threading
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.Text
open System.IO
open Microsoft.Win32

[<AutoOpen>]
module volLib =
    type volTypes = GB = 1000000000L | Min_c = 5000000000L | Min_d = 10000000000L

    let libInit = ref false

    let driveList () = 
        DriveInfo.GetDrives()

    let freeSpace drive =
        let di = DriveInfo(drive)
        di.AvailableFreeSpace
```

Comment: Move the enums outside the module.

Comment: @Gustavo But how to reference them from the linking program?

Comment: As usual, click on add references, browse, select the dll ... otherwise what's special with this?

Comment: I can access the functions, but not the enums.

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion regarding the enum?

Comment: @Gustavo Yes, and I could not reference it in the linking program. I did move the enums outside the module.

Comment: Could you edit the question to include the code where you try to access the enum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `libInit` and the other functions from the module are visible, it means you have linked your library correctly.

If you try to access the enum, you need to prefix it with the enum name, like:

```
let accessEnum = volTypes.GB
```

That is different than what you can do with F# discriminated union types. If you define a union like

```
type volUnion = 
    | GB2
    | Min_c2
    | Min_d2
```

then you can access each case just by its name, like:

```
let accessUnion = GB2
```